# Построить запрос на вывод сотрудников из базы данных

Tags: php, sql, cms

Всем привет ! Ребят помогите в моих первых начинаниях в написании своей админки

**1)** Существует таблица с проектами: (portfolio)

**2)** Так же создана таблица со всеми сотрудниками(sotrudniki)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**3)** В панели администрирования при добавление новой работы прикрепляються сотрудники учавстовавшие при создании проекта. Данные храняться в таблице (post_tags)

postid=ID проекта, tagid=ID сотрудника
С записью данных в базу у меня всё получилось, все данные правильно разносятся по табличкам.
А вот с выводом на странице проекта, проблема. Выводятся в моем случае четыре записи только одинаковые.
Код PHP для вывода

```html
<?php 
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM portfolio WHERE id=$id");      
  $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

  $resultworkers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts_tags",$db);
  $myrowworkers = mysql_fetch_array($resultworkers);

  $resultsupport= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sotrudniki",$db);
  $myrowsupport = mysql_fetch_array($resultsupport);

  $count = mysql_num_rows($resultworkers);

  do 
  {

   if ($myrow['id'] == $myrowworkers ['postid'])
   {
    printf ("<div class='team_block'>
     <img src='images/%s' alt='Pixwhite'>
     <div class='desc'>
      <span>%s</span>
      <p>%s</p>
     </div>
    </div>",$myrowsupport["sotrundikimg"],$myrowsupport["dolgnost"],$myrowsupport["fio"]);
   }
   else
   {
    
   }               

  }
  while ($myrowworkers = mysql_fetch_array($resultworkers));


  ?>
```

Comment: 1. Учи джойны. 2. выкини на помойку mysql_query и используй PDO. За имя таблицы posts_tags в которой лежат связи сотрудников с проектами тебя будут долго и с наслаждением бить ногами, когда поймают.

Comment: А, фирменное do..while из видеокурсов попова. ну тогда тебе уже ничего не поможет.

Comment: За попова ждал комментов) Потихоньку весь код исправляеться, но к моему сожалению начиналось всё с его курса.

Comment: http://phpforum.su/index.php?showtopic=32799 Для попвщины есть курс реабилитации :)

Comment: Котеров и Костарев сейчас моя реабилитация)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этой задачи необходимо использовать JOIN.
Для вашей структуры SQL запрос будет примерно таким:

```
SELECT *
FROM sotrudniki as s 
INNER JOIN post_tags pt on s.id = pt.tagid
INNER JOIN portfolio p on p.id = pt.postid;
```

Попробуйте выполнить этот запрос в PHPMyAdmin и увидите, что результаты трех таблиц объединены. Но я бы на вашем месте называл имена таблиц и полей нормальными именами на латинице без транслита.

Советую прочитать про JOIN в MYSQL, синонимы таблиц *(select from teble **as t**)*. Вместо `SELECT *` перечислите необходимые для выборки поля (кстати, тоже рабротает конструкция as).

Comment: В моем примере у вас не выведутся сотрудники без портфолио или портфолио без сотрудников. Если это нужно, не используйте `INNER` перед `JOIN`

Comment: Если не использовать INNER перед JOIN, то не изменится ровно ничего

Comment: Всё хорошо выводиться, только на всех страницах проектов. Только почему то все записи на всех работах. Как дополнить код что бы в каждом проекте были свои сотрудники ?
**$resultworker = mysql_query("SELECT sotrundikimg,dolgnost,fio
   FROM `sotrudniki` as s 
   JOIN `portfolio_workers` pt on s.id = pt.tagid
   JOIN `portfolio` p on p.id = pt.postid", $db);**

Comment: Если у каждой работы есть свой id который прописан в url. Например **?id=67**

Comment: Добавьте условие в запрос. `where p.id = нужный id`

Comment: Супер ! Всё работает как надо, дай бог вам здоровьечка добрый человек ! :D